# Can a GDBM database created in C be opened in Python?

Tags: python, c, macos, magic-numbers, gdbm

I have a Python program in which I am trying to use [this rhyming dictionary](http://rhyme.sourceforge.net/) to look up rhymes.

Part of the dictionary library  setup works by a C program creating three gdbm `.db` files. The code that does this is publicly available [here](http://rhyme.sourceforge.net/) (from 'get the source' section), and the key part of the C gdbm builder `compile.c` looks like this:

```
#include <gdbm.h>

...<snip>...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *input;
  GDBM_FILE output;

...<snip>...

output = gdbm_open(argv[2], 0, GDBM_NEWDB, 0644, 0);

...<snip>...

gdbm_sync(output);

...<snip>...
```

`words.db` is created, and it can be successfully accessed from the bundled command line interface.

According to [the library's example page](http://rhyme.sourceforge.net/how.html), I should be able to use the python gdbm module to access the database.

However, I cannot. When I run the following:

```
import gdbm
words = gdbm.open('/usr/share/rhyme/words.db')
```

I get the following error:

```
    words = gdbm.open('/usr/share/rhyme/words.db')
gdbm.error: Bad magic number
```

Is there a file incompatibility problem? Do some gdbm files created in C not open with Python?

(This is with Python 2.7 on OSX 10.6.8. Python's gdbm was installed via MacPorts)

Comment: Works fine for me:

 r["AY1-M"] = 
    "ANTICRIME BEIM CHIME CLIMB CLIME CRIME DIME GRIME HAIM HEIM HIME I'M KIME LIME LYME MIME ONETIME PART-TIME PRIME RHYME RIME SEIM SIME SLIME SUBLIME SYME THYME TIME"


I compiled the database using the standard "libgdbm-dev" package on Ubuntu (Precise), and read it with Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Ok thanks, this makes me think that it is an OSX-specific problem. Probably to do with the flavour of GDBM I have installed via MacPorts vs the OS's GDBM.

Comment: Hey Bill.  Were you able to remove the library?  Were you able to compare the gdbm headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create the words.db file?  It looks like the words.db is corrupted or in a format not supported by your specific version of the gdbm library on Mac OS X.

Comment: The gdbm files are created by a C program on my platform; I have given snippets of the code used in my question, and the whole source file of this C program is also linked in the question. So the problem seems to be that the gdbm files created by C on my platform cannot be read by Python on my platform.

Comment: As a quick test, write a python program to create an empty gdbm database.  Compare the headers of both .db files--the one created by your C program and the one created by Python.  Check if the first 2 or 4 bytes are the same?  Maybe you installed two different libgdbm libraries?

Comment: I think I did install two different libraries - the C one from source and the Python via MacPorts. I will do as you suggested and comapare the headers.

Comment: The error message means that the "magic number" used to identify the file as a GNU dbm file does not match what the libgdbm was expecting.  These magic numbers are usually the first 2-4 bytes in a file.  One library may be expecting something different.

You could also do a "make uninstall" from the source code and uninstall the installed library.  If you're lucky this will work.

Comment: If the libraries produced two different headers then make sure to come back and mention that.  It could help someone else later.

Comment: Ok thanks, I now have this figured out. For some reason, as you suggest, the first couple of bytes of gdbm files created in C are different to those created in Python. I manually changed the C one to match the Python one with a Hex editor, and now it works! Only a one-time solution, but it does the trick for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the creator of Python (all kneel down and repeat *we are not worthy!* x3 :-)

> Simple -- gdbm is sensitive to the byte order.  Alas, I don't know
>   what to do about it except converting it to a more portable format for
>   transfer, or patching the gdbm source :-(
>
> --Guido van Rossum (home page: http://www.python.org/~guido/)